# Determine all complex numbers satisfying the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

The equation:
$$e^{iz} = 4\cos(z) + 3$$
This is what I have tried so far:
$$e^{iz} = 4\left(\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right)+3$$
$$e^{iz} = 2e^{iz}+2^{-iz}+3$$
$$e^{2iz} = 2e^{2iz}+2+3e^{iz}$$
$$e^{2iz}+3e^{iz}+2=0$$
Now, I substitute $e^{iz}$ with $x$, resulting in $x=-1$ or $x=-2$.
This leaves me at $e^{iz}=-1$ or $e^{iz}=-2$
I'm not sure how to continue from here. I can get rid of the $e$ by taking the natural logarithm, but that makes further calculations very difficult.

Comment: Take logarithms, as you said. For example, $\ln(-1)=\ln(e^{\pi i + 2k\pi i})=\pi i + 2k\pi i$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $e^{iz}=-1$ gives you the solutions $z=\pi+2k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The key step is the first: writing $-1$ in its polar form $e^{i\pi}$. The polar form of $-2$ is $2e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: Wow, that really helps. For $z=-2$ I end up with $z = ln(2)\pi + 2ki\pi$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, almost: $z=2k\pi+\pi-i\ln2$.

Comment: Do you get to $-i ln(2)$ by multiplying $\frac{ln(2)}{i}$ by $\frac{-i}{-i}$?

Comment: Yes, that shows $\frac{\ln2}i=-i\ln2$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following well-known properties of the complex exponential function:
$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \forall z' \in \mathbb{C}:$

- $e^{z} e^{z'}=e^{z+z'}$;
- $e^z=1\iff\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}, z=2ik\pi$.

From these properties, it follows that :  $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, e^z\neq0$;   $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \forall z' \in \mathbb{C}, e^z=e^{z'}\iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z},z=z'+2ik\pi$.

So, $e^{iz}=-1=e^{i\pi}\iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z},iz=i\pi+2ik\pi\iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z},z=\pi+2k\pi$
$e^{iz}=-2=e^{i\pi}e^{log2}=e^{i\pi+log2}\iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z},iz=i\pi+log2+2ik\pi\iff \exists k\in \mathbb{Z},z=\pi+2k\pi-ilog2$